# Convergence in measure - product

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to prove the following statements in Folland's book.

*Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. If $f_n\to f$ in measure and $g_n\to g$ in measure, then $f_n+g_n\to f+g$ in measure and $f_ng_n\to fg$ in measure (in this last case, assume $\mu(X)<\infty$).*

The first one is already done, but the second one is giving me trouble.

**My attempt:** We can take subsequences $f_{n_k}$ and $g_{n_k}$ such that $f_{n_k}\to f$ a.e. and $g_{n_k}\to g$ a.e. In this case, we know that $f_{n_k}g_{n_k}\to fg$ a.e. Note that $\mu(X)<\infty$, so we can use Egoroff's theorem to conclude that $f_{n_k}g_{n_k}\to fg$ almost uniformly. Finally, almost uniform convergence implies convergence in measure, therefore $f_{n_k}g_{n_k}\to fg$ in measure.

The problem is that I just have convergence in measure for some subsequence of $f_ng_n$ and I need convergence in measure for the whole sequence. Also I don't know if using Egoroff's theorem is unnecessary, if this is the case, I would appreciate to see some more elementary prove.

**Detail:** We say that $f_n\to f$ *almost uniformly* if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $E\subset X$ measurable, such that $\mu(E) <\varepsilon$ and $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $E^c$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is something which is sometimes called the **subsequence principle**. It states that $x_n \to x$ holds if and only if every subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ admits a further subsequence $(x_{n_{k_l}})_l$, which converges to $x$. Note that the limit $x$ has to be fixed.

This holds as soon as the notion of convergence is induced by a topology.

This should help you here.

Interesting sidenote: Using this property, one can show that convergence a.e. (of measurable functions on $\Bbb{R}$) is not induced by a topology.

For the proof of the principle, note that "$\Rightarrow$" is trivial (use $(x_{n_k})_k$ itself for the "further subsequence". For "$\Leftarrow$", assume that $x_n \to x$ is false. Then (by definition) there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that for each $N\in \Bbb{N}$, there is some $n_N \geq N$ with $x_{n_N}\notin U$. Inductively, this allows to construct a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ with $x_{n_k}\notin U$ for all $k$. But by assumption, there is a further subsequence $(x_{n_{k_l}})_l$ which converges to $x$. In particular, for $l$ large enough, $x_{n_{k_l}}\in U$ (because $U$ is an neighborhood of $x$), contradiction.

EDIT: Here is another possible proof: Using the subsequence principle, you can also show the following equivalence on a space of **finite** measure:

A sequence $(f_n)_n$ of measurable functions converges in measure to $f$ iff every subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ has a further subsequence $(f_{n_{k_\ell}})_\ell$ which converges pointwise a.e. to $f$.

Once you have shown this characterization, you can derive your claim as a corollary.

Comment: Do you have a link with the proof of this principle. I don't want to use results without knowing their proofs.

Comment: Don't worry about that anymore, I could help myself.

Comment: Could you give just one more hint. How should I use this result to prove what I want to prove? Thanks.

Comment: @Integral: Take **any** subsequence $(f_{n_k} g_{n_k})_k$ of the product sequence you are considering. By the argument you noted yourself, there is a further subsequence $(f_{n_{k_l}} g_{n_{k_l}})_l$ so that each of the two sequences $(f_{n_{k_l}})_l$ and $(g_{n_{k_l}})_l$ converge pointwise a.e. This yields (e.g. by your Egoroff argument, since the space is of finite measure) that $(f_{n_{k_l}} g_{n_{k_l}})_l$ converges almost uniformly (hence in measure) to $fg$. Now apply the subsequence principle.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks. Well, there is just one more point I would like to clarify. To me looks that this principle could change "all subsequences have a subsequence converging to the same limit $x$" for "all subsequences converges to the same limit $x$". Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, there is one more point I don't get. How do you know that $(f_{n_k}g_{n_k})$ have a subsequence converging pointwise a.e. ? I mean, in my argument I can take some pointwise a.e. subsequence from a sequence converging in measure. But I don't know that $(f_{n_k}g_{n_k})$ converges in measure to use this.

Comment: Ok, the second is more important. So, that's the thing, the subsequence $(f_{n_{k_l}})_l$ does not necessarily has the same index of $(g_{n_{k_l}})_l$. You just know the existence of this subsequeces, we can't choose their indexes. Therefore the indexes of their product will not agree, this is a problem, because all the measures in this context deal with same index, after all, we are working with the sets $$\{x: |f_n(x)g_n(x)-f(x)g(x)|\geq\varepsilon\}$$

Comment: @Integral: The point is the following: Take a subsequence $(f_{n_{k_\ell}})_\ell$ of $(f_{n_k})_k$ which converges pointwise a.e. Then take a **further** subsequence $(g_{n_{k_{\ell_m}}})_m$ which also converges pointwise a.e. Then **both** subsequences, $(f_{n_{k_{\ell_m}}})_m$ and $(g_{n_{k_{\ell_m}}})_m$ converge poinwise a.e. I will also edit my post in the next minutes with a slightly easier proof.

Comment: I'm really not following, you are writing the indexes as they are the same, but they not necessarily are. We dont **take** subsequences converging a.e., we just know they **exist** and we use them, but we can't choose.  Maybe will be better if I make an example of what is bugging me. We have the sequences $f_n$ and $g_n$. Now we take **any** subsequence, to make things clear, let's take $\{f_2,f_4,\ldots\}$ and $\{g_2, g_4,\ldots\}$, the subsequences with even indexes.

Comment: We now **there is** a subsequence of $\{f_2, f_4, \ldots\}$ converging a.e. to $f$, suppose this subsequence is $\{f_{10}, f_{20},\ldots\}$, with the index being all multiples of $10$. On the other side, we know **there is** a subsequence of $\{g_2, g_4,\ldots\}$ converging a.e. to $g$, suppose this subsequence is $\{g_{12}, g_{22},\ldots\}$, with the index being all multiples of $10$ plus $2$. In this view, there is no way in can use the product os this subsequences to argue something, because we need products of the form $f_ng_n$, the indexes must agree.

Comment: In your example, consider the sequence $(h_n)_n = \{g_10, g_20, \dots\}$. This sequence **still converges in measure to $g$,** since it is a subsequence of $(g_n)_n$. Hence, there is a subsequence **of $(h_n)_n$,** which maybe takes each 3rd entry of $(h_n)_n$ such that $(h_{3n})_n$ converges pointwise a.e. to $g$. But $(h_{3n})_n = (g_{30}, g_{90}, \dots)$. Since $(f_{30}, f_{90}, \dots)$ is **also** a subsequence of $(f_{10}, f_{20}, \dots)$, which we know converges pointwise a.e., everything is fine.

Comment: Now it's 100% done. Thank you very much your patience. I really learned a lot.

Comment: @PhoemueX. Thank you for your claim. I follow your hints and submit the proof as follows.

Answer (score 7):

I prove PhoemueX's claim as follows.

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(X)<\infty$.
Let $f_{n}:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
be measurable functions. Then the following are equivalent:

(1) $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in measure,

(2) Every subsequence of $\{f_{n}\}$ has a subsequence that converges
to $f$ a.e.

Proof: To prove $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$: Let $\{f_{n_{k}}\}$ be a subsequence
of $\{f_{n}\}$. To simplify notation, we denote $g_{k}=f_{n_{k}}$.
Clearly $g_{n}\rightarrow f$ in measure. Choose integers $n_{k}$
inductively such that $n_{1}<n_{2}<\ldots$ and $\mu\left(\left[|g_{n_{k}}-f|\geq\frac{1}{k}\right]\right)\leq\frac{1}{2^{k}}$.
To further simplify notation, let $h_{k}=g_{n_{k}}$. We assert that
$h_{n}\rightarrow f$ a.e.. Define $A=\{x\in X\mid\lim_{n}h_{n}(x)=f(x)\}$.
Observe that 
$$
A^{c}=\bigcup_{l=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x\mid|h_{n}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{l}\}.
$$
We go to show that, for each $l\in\mathbb{N}$, $\mu\left(\bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x\mid|h_{n}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{l}\}\right)=0$.
For each $N$, denote $B_{N}=\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty}\{x\mid|h_{n}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{l}\}$.
For $n\geq l$, we have $\{x\mid|h_{n}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{l}\}\subseteq\{x\mid|h_{n}(x)-f(x)\mid\geq\frac{1}{n}\}$,
so for any $N\geq l$, 
$$
\mu\left(B_{N}\right)\leq\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\mu\left(\{x\mid|h_{n}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{l}\}\right)\leq\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\mu\left(\{x\mid|h_{n}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{n}\}\right)\leq\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}.
$$
Observe that $B_{1}\supseteq B_{2}\supseteq\ldots$ and **$\mu$
is finite**, we have $\mu(\cap_{N}B_{N})=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\mu(B_{N})=0$.
Therefore, $\mu(A^{c})=0$ and hence $h_{n}\rightarrow f$ a.e.

To prove $(2)\Rightarrow(1)$: Prove by contradiction. Suppose the
contrary that $f_{n}\not\rightarrow f$ in measure. Then there exists
$\delta_{1}>0$ such that $\mu\left(\left[|f_{n}-f|\geq\delta_{1}\right]\right)\not\rightarrow0$.
There further exist $\delta_{2}>0$ and a subsequence $(n_{k})$ such
that for each $k$, $\mu\left(\left[|f_{n_{k}}-f|\geq\delta_{1}\right]\right)\geq\delta_{2}.$
Define $\delta=\min(\delta_{1},\delta_{2})$. In particular, we have
$\mu\left(\left[|f_{n_{k}}-f|\geq\delta\right]\right)\geq\delta$.
To further simplify notation, denote $g_{k}=f_{n_{k}}$. Then $(g_{n})$
is a subsequence of $(f_{n})$ and $\mu\left(\left[|g_{n}-f|\geq\delta\right]\right)\geq\delta$
for each $n$. By assumption, $(g_{n})$ has a subsequence $(g_{n_{k}})$
that converges to $f$ a.e.. Define $D=\{x\mid g_{n_{k}}(x)\rightarrow f(x)\}$,
then 
$$
D^{c}=\bigcup_{l=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=N}^{\infty}\{x\mid|g_{n_{k}}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{l}\}.
$$
Choose $l$ such that $\frac{1}{l}<\delta$. Note that $\mu(D^{c})=0$,
and in particular, $\mu\left(\bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=N}^{\infty}\{x\mid|g_{n_{k}}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{l}\}\right)=0.$
Note that **$\mu$ is finite** and $\left(\bigcup_{k=N}^{\infty}\{x\mid|g_{n_{k}}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{l}\}\right)_{N}$
is a decreasing sequence of measurable sets. Therefore 
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=N}^{\infty}\{x\mid|g_{n_{k}}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{l}\}\right)=\mu\left(\bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=N}^{\infty}\{x\mid|g_{n_{k}}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{l}\}\right)=0.
$$
Choose $N$ such that $\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=N}^{\infty}\{x\mid|g_{n_{k}}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{l}\}\right)<\delta$.
Observe that for each $k\geq N$, $\{x\mid|g_{n_{k}}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{l}\}\supseteq\{x\mid|g_{n_{k}}(x)-f(x)|\geq\delta\}$,
so 
$$
\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=N}^{\infty}\{x\mid|g_{n_{k}}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{l}\}\right)\geq\mu\left(\{x\mid|g_{n_{N}}(x)-f(x)|\geq\delta\}\right)\geq\delta
$$
which is a contradiction.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

By using the claim, we can prove that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ and $g_{n}\rightarrow g$
in measure $\Rightarrow$ $f_{n}g_{n}\rightarrow fg$ in measure immediately.

For, let $\left(f_{n_{k}}g_{n_{k}}\right)_{k}$ be an arbitrary subsequence
of $(f_{n}g_{n})_{n}$. $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in measure implies that
for the subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})_{k}$, there exists a subsequence
$(f_{n_{k_{l}}})_{l}$ such that $f_{n_{k_{l}}}\rightarrow f$ a.e..
$g_{n}\rightarrow g$ in measure implies that for the subsequence
$(g_{n_{k_{l}}})_{l}$, there exists a further subsequence $(g_{n_{k_{l_{p}}}})_{p}$
such that $g_{n_{k_{l_{p}}}}\rightarrow g$ a.e.. Now, we have $f_{n_{k_{l_{p}}}}g_{n_{k_{l_{p}}}}\rightarrow fg$ a.e..
By the claim, we have $f_{n}g_{n}\rightarrow fg$ in measure.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is based on the result here [product case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336113/prove-that-if-f-n-converges-to-f-in-measure-then-f-n2-converges-to-f)

And the rest of proof is based on the first result