# Prove that if $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in measure then $(f_n^2)$ converges to $f^2$ in measure.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $E$ be a measurable set with finite measure, $(f_n)$ be a sequence of real-valued measurable functions on $E$ and $f$ be a real valued measurable function on $E$. It is required to prove that if $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in measure then $(f_n^2)$ converges to $f^2$ in measure. The following is my attempt.

Suppose $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in measure. Let $(f_{n_k})$ be a subsequence of $(f_n)$. Then $(f_{n_k})$ converges to $f$ in measure and there exists a subsequence $(f_{{n_k}_r})$ that converges to $f$ pointwise a.e. on $E$. Hence $f^2$ is such that for any subsequence of the sequence $(f_n^2)$, there exists a further subsequence that converges to $f^2$ pointwise a.e. on $E$, and therefore $(f_n^2)$ converges to $f^2$ pointwise a.e. on E. Now since $m(E)$ is finite, we have $(f_n^2)$ converges to $f^2$ in measure.

Is the above argument alright? Thanks.

Comment: It's not true that a.e. convergence of a further subsequence $(f_{n_{k_{r}}})$ for each subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})$ to $f^2$ implies a.e. convergence of $f^2$. For an alternative solution: What do you know about convergence in measure?

Comment: Why is it not true? I know it is true for sequences of real numbers but why not in this case? I've studied a chapter called "Modes of convergence".

Comment: If this was the case, every $L^1$-convergent sequence $(f_n ) \rightarrow f$ would be a.e. convergent: Each subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})$ also converges to $f$ in $L^1$ and thus has a further subsequence that converges a.e. to $f$. A common counterexample is a sequence on $[ 0,1)$, where $f_1=1_{[ 0,\frac{1}{2})}$, $f_2=1_{[\frac{1}{2},1)}$, $f_3=1_{[ 0,\frac{1}{4})}$... This sequence converges to 0 in $L^1$ but there is no pointwise convergence in **any** point.

Comment: I agree. Could you give a hint for an alternative solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Addition to the comment above, here is an alternative idea. There are probably more elegant solutions (e.g. more similar to your approach), but this should work as well.
\begin{align}
&\mu \left(x\in E: \vert f^2(x)-f_n^2(x)\vert \geq \epsilon \right) \\
=&\mu \left(x\in E: \vert f(x)+f_n(x)\vert \vert f(x)-f_n(x)\vert \geq \epsilon \right)\\
=&\mu \left(x\in E: \vert f(x)+f_n(x)\vert \vert f(x)-f_n(x)\vert \geq \epsilon \text{ and } \vert f(x)+f_n(x)\vert > k \right) + \mu \left(x\in E: \vert f(x)+f_n(x)\vert \vert f(x)-f_n(x)\vert \geq \epsilon \text{ and } \vert f(x)+f_n(x)\vert\leq k \right)\\
\leq&\mu \left(x\in E: \vert f(x)+f_n(x)\vert > k \right) + \mu \left(x\in E:  \vert f(x)-f_n(x)\vert \geq \frac{\epsilon}{k}  \right)\\
\end{align}

By $\sigma$-continuity of $\mu$ and since $\mu (E) < \infty$, the first term converges to 0, for $k\rightarrow \infty$. For any fixed $k$, the second term converges to 0 for $n\rightarrow\infty$, since $f_n  \rightarrow f$ in measure. Now, choosing sufficiently large $k$ and then letting $n\rightarrow \infty$ makes
$$
\mu \left(x\in E: \vert f^2(x)-f_n^2(x)\vert \geq \epsilon \right)
$$
arbitrarily small.

Comment: Can you give more details on why the first term converges to 0 when $\mu < \infty$?

Comment: The intersection of these sets for all k is the empty set, which has measure zero. All measures have what is called „continuity from above“, which means that the measures of such „decreasing“ sets converge to the measure of their intersection - if at least at some point the sets have finite measure. See here under „Basic Properties“: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)

Answer (score 3):

Convergence in measure means that $\mu(\{x: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \ge \epsilon\})$ tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Fix $\epsilon$ and $\eta > 0$, and choose sufficiently large $M, N > 0$ such that $\mu(\{x: |f(x)|> M\}) < \frac{\eta}{3}$ and $\mu(\{x: |f_n(x)|> M\}) < \frac{\eta}{3}$ for $n \ge N$.

(We can do this because $A_m = \{x: |f(x)| > m\}$ has $A_1 \supset ... \supset A_m \supset ...$ and the intersection $\cap_mA_m$ clearly is empty, so that since $\lim_{m \to \infty} \mu (A_m) = \mu (\cap_mA_m) = 0$, at some point we must have $\mu(A_m) < \frac{\eta}{6}$. It's in this step that we have used the finite measure property, since otherwise $\lim_{m \to \infty} \mu (A_m) = \mu (\cap_mA_m)$ isn't necessarily true. As to the $f_n$'s, for $N$ sufficiently large we have $|f_n(x)| < |f(x)| + \epsilon$ if $n \ge N$, except on a set $E_N$ with $\mu(E_N) < \frac{\eta}{6}$. To get our $M$, we take $m$ so large that $\mu(A_m) < \frac{\eta}{6}$ and thus $\mu(A_m \cup E_N) < \frac{\eta}{3}$. By selecting $M = m + \epsilon$ and $n \ge N$ we obtain $\{x: |f(x)|> M\} \subset A_m$ and $\{x: |f_n(x)|> M\} \subset A_m \cup E_N$, so we have our $M$ and $N$.)

Now $\{x: |f(x)|> M\} \cup \{x: |f_n(x)|> M\}$ has measure at most $\frac{2\eta}{3}$; on the complement of this set, we have \begin{eqnarray}|f_n(x)^2 - f(x)^2| &&=&& |f_n(x) - f(x)|\cdot|f_n(x) + f(x)| \le |f_n(x) - f(x)| \cdot \Big( |f_n(x)| + |f(x| \Big)\\ &&\le && |f_n(x) - f(x)|\cdot2M&&
\end{eqnarray}
and so by choosing $n$ large enough (and larger than $N$), we can make this expression less than $\epsilon$ on all of our remaining set, except for a part with measure less than $\frac{\eta}{3}$. Therefore $$\mu(\{x: |f_n(x)^2 - f(x)^2| \ge \epsilon\}) < \frac{2\eta}{3} + \frac{\eta}{3} = \eta$$ for $n$ large enough, where $\epsilon$ and $\eta$ were arbitrary - which proves the claim.

Comment: We don't know if $f(x)$ is finite for all $x$.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if my proof is correct and would be so appreciated if someone can confirm it. We will prove $f_n^2 \rightarrow f^2$ in measure. Assume not, then it means that there exists an $\epsilon_0 > 0$, such that for all $\delta > 0$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have: 
$\mu(\{x: |f_n(x)^2 - f(x)^2| \geq \delta\}) \geq \epsilon_0 \implies \mu(\{x: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \frac{\delta}{|f_n(x)| + |f(x)|}\}) \geq \epsilon_0 $(*)

But then observe that since $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure, this means that for any $\epsilon$ and especially for $\epsilon_0$, we can find a $\delta_0 > 0$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n > N$ we have :

$\mu(\{x: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \delta_0\}) \leq \epsilon_0 $

Now since the ($*$) was true for every $\delta$, pick $\delta$ to be $\delta = \delta_0.\sup_{x \in [0,1]}(|f_n(x)| + |f(x)|)$. Then we can see ($*$) will be, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$\mu(\{x: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \delta_0\}) \geq \mu((\{x: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \frac{\delta}{|f_n(x)| + |f(x)|}\})) \geq \epsilon_0 $

Which is a contradiction to saying $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure.
And see that almost everywhere $\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f_n(x)| + |f(x)|$ exists, because the set $\mu(x: |f_n(x)| + |f(x)| > N) \rightarrow
 0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$ by $\sigma$-continuity of measure, and hence $\delta$ is well-defined almost every where, and that's all we need.

Comment: Answer fields are reserved for answers, and not for requests solution/proof verification.  Your post is a request, not an answer.